# Is this OpenTokRTC javascript framework only? Or will it work on Rails too?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement this project into my rails project, but i'm not sure if it's possible to do so since it's it's using a different type of framework (i think?). I'm very new to rails, so please excuse me if this is a very stupid question.

Github: https://github.com/opentok/OpenTokRTC

Demo: https://opentokrtc.com/

Comment: Given that the server is run via NodeJS, I'd say probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can. You just need to use the correct [server SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/ruby/) and [client SDK](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/js/). The Github repository you mentioned is a node.js demo app. You can find Ruby based one https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-Ruby-SDK